# What fraction of the job can be done by one man in one day given 10 men can do a job in 10 days?

Tags: puzzle

> If 10 men can do a job in 10 days.What fraction of the job can be done by one man in one day?

My Approach:

$10$M . $10$D=$100$MD ($10$ men take $10$ days =$100$ man days)

$1$ . $1$=$1/100$ (i.e 1 men in 1 day do)

Am i right in my approach?

Answer (score 1):

The 10 men do 1 job in 10 days, so 1 man does 1/10 of the job in the 10 days. 
so 1 man does 1/100 of the job in 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Ten men ten days. 1 man does 1/10 of the work in 10 days. Then he will do 1/100 work in one day.